# Cannot override data-aplay data attribute in jQuery on hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the autoscroll function in my slider on hover, and similarly when I move the mouse away, begin the slider once again. The data attribute isn't getting updated. Even though it's showing in console.

HTML code:

```
<div id="featured" class="swiper-container gloria-sliders events-list-carousel swiper-container-horizontal swiper-container-undefined" data-item="3" data-column-space="1" data-sloop="true" data-aplay="4000">
```

As you can see, it is setting the data attribute `data-aplay` to `4000` by default.

Attaching script below:

```
<script>
 $("#featured").hover( function () {
 console.log('hover');
 var featured = $('#featured').data('aplay','false');
 console.log($('#featured').data('aplay'));
}, function() {
 console.log('not hovered');    
 $('#featured').data('aplay','4000');
 console.log($('#featured').data('aplay')); 
}); 
</script>
```

When I hover, it displays:

`hover`

`false`

But it doesn't update the `data-aplay` value, also when I remove the hover it displays

`not hovered`

`4000`

If any additional info is required, please let me know. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You

**UPDATE**

```
var stopScroll = setInterval(function(){ $(".metalhead").click(); }, 4000) ;

 $('.oswald, .image a').click(function() {
    clearInterval(stopScroll);
    });

 $('#featured').mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(stopScroll);
 }).mouseout(function(){
    stopScroll = setInterval(function(){ $(".metalhead").click(); }, 4000) ;
 })
```

I am using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` now. It is working to some extent. But still not accurate

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-right metalhead" id="scroll" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

So what I am doing now is adding a function to click on the right arrow every 4 seconds. So on `mouseover` I am using `clearInterval` to remove the timer and on `mouseout` using `setInterval` to revert back to 4 seconds.

I have also added another function, which stops the slider when a particular item is clicked. Still not confident it is working correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe it is changing the data property properly, only that does not update the *view* of the attribute, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var featured=$('#featured');
 featured.hover( function () {
 console.log('hover');
 featured.data('aplay','false');
 featured.removeAttr('data-aplay')
 console.log(featured.data('aplay'));
}, function() {
 console.log('not hovered');    
 featured.attr('data-aplay', '4000')
 featured.data('aplay','4000');
 console.log(featured.data('aplay')); 
}); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I will have a look at this.

Comment: UPDATE: That did remove the attribute, but my slider is still moving on hover. Is there anyway to override it?

Comment: `.prop()` or `.attr()` are the functions that impact the attribute. `.data()` is a memory bag. Read here: http://www.jqapi.com/#p=prop

Comment: @Benny So what I am trying over here won't work? Is there any other solution for the same?

Comment: @davidnoronha can you post the full code online in Codepen or Jsfiddle etc.? It will help us help you

Comment: @Benny The thing is it's a wordpress site and the carousel is from the theme. I have updated the code, but it's still not working as planned. I will update the code here, so you can assist me from that.

Comment: @davidnoronha in what way is it not working? And why is it inaccurate (your words)?